# How can I remove temporary files created by fs.lstat?

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a simple method below which checks to see if a directory exists. I have noticed that when **fs.lstat** get's called it creates, what looks like a *temporary file* with a name along the lines of '12116-ocskz3'

**Why does lstat create these temporary files and how can I remove them?**

```
self.checkDirectory = function (callback) {
    fs.lstat(uploadDir, function (err, stats) {
        // Linux fielsystem manual - http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat
        if (!err && stats.isDirectory()) {

            //Directory exists
            console.log('This directory already exists!');

            if (typeof(callback) == 'function') {
                callback(true, uploadDir);
            }

        } else if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            // ENOENT - A component of path does not exist, or path is an empty string.
            console.log(err.code + ': This directory doesn\'t exists!');

            if (typeof(callback) == 'function') {
                callback(false, uploadDir);
            }

        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was caused by using the encrypt attribute on the form element with the value seen below:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data
```

I think multipart is being replaced with something more favorable in a future release due, issues with temporary files being one of the reasons I think.

Answer (score 0):

lstat does not create any temporary files

---

Edit: okay, as discovered in comments, `multipart` module is creating them. It has been blogged about [several times](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html), just search for it somewhere.

The easiest solution is to not use bodyParser (it's deprecated anyway for precisely this reason), use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` instead. If you really need to upload files, read [docs](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) about how to deal with them. It should be somewhere in `req.files` afair.

Comment: That's what I would have assumed, but in my case it is. I'm not calling any other fs method in my application. I wonder if this is a Windows quirk?

Comment: oh... sorry, maybe it is. I don't remember anyone using windows for long time, so I forgot that those quirks even existed. If it is really a windows quirk, node.js should remove them automatically upon exit. If it doesn't, you should probably report it [here](https://github.com/joyent/libuv)

Comment: Hmm...it's not removing them. I'll get the app installed on my mac and report back later.

Comment: Ok i've found that removing:

`{uploadDir: __dirname + '/uploads'}`

from:

`app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir: __dirname + '/uploads'}));`

stops this from happening, but it doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: No, in fact it does explain the issue. I updated the answer to explain this.